# My program executes the else statements even though it should stop on the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

My program proceeds to the else statement even though the user inputs the correct answer and the if statement is run.

```
package dowhileloops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhileLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String res, ans;
        
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("     ****     Do-While Loops     ****    ");
        System.out.println("=========================================\n");
        
        do{
            System.out.println("What is the color of the ocean?");
            System.out.println("\nA.) Orange\n\nB.) Green\n\nC.) Blue\n\nD.) Yellow\n\n");
            System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
            res = in.nextLine();

            if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                System.out.println("You are correct!");
                else
                    System.out.println("You are wrong!");
                        System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Yes/No)");
                        ans = in.nextLine();
               
        }while(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));        
    }
    
}
```

It proceeds to execute the line
`System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Yes/No)"); ans = in.nextLine();` even though it should stop at `System.out.println("You are correct!");`

I want the program to terminate after the user types the correct answer "C"

Comment: You should have curly-braces after your else. You can omit them, but it will only execute _one_ statement after. You have 3.

Comment: Always use curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you did not put curly brackest `{` and `}`.

Here is the code with the curly brackets.

```java
package dowhileloops;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhileLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String res, ans;

        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("     ****     Do-While Loops     ****    ");
        System.out.println("=========================================\n");

        do {
            System.out.println("What is the color of the ocean?");
            System.out.println("\nA.) Orange\n\nB.) Green\n\nC.) Blue\n\nD.) Yellow\n\n");
            System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
            res = in.nextLine();

            if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                System.out.println("You are correct!");
            else {
                System.out.println("You are wrong!");
                System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Yes/No)");
                ans = in.nextLine();
            }

        } while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }
}
```

========

Edit #1:
It is not the optimum solution, but it works. I tried to run your code correctly with the minimum amount of editing

```java
package dowhileloops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhileLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String res, ans;

        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("     ****     Do-While Loops     ****    ");
        System.out.println("=========================================\n");

        do {
            System.out.println("What is the color of the ocean?");
            System.out.println("\nA.) Orange\n\nB.) Green\n\nC.) Blue\n\nD.) Yellow\n\n");
            System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
            res = in.nextLine();

            if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                System.out.println("You are correct!");
                ans = "No";
            } else {
                System.out.println("You are wrong!");
                System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Yes/No)");
                ans = in.nextLine();
            }

        } while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }
}
```

Comment: After I did this, an error pops up on the "while" line where it says the variable "ans" is not initiated.

Comment: @Clorky The assign an initial value to `ans` when you declare it

Comment: I will debug your code now. However, it is a famous mistake to forget to put curly brackets for multi-lines blocks of codes.

Comment: @Clorky I edited the answer, and it is working now.

Comment: @Ambitions Ohh wait that was actually such a simple yet clever solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should accept the char not the string.

```
res = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

this will accept the first char no matter the rest of the chars.
and use curly brace after for else statement.

Answer (score 0):

As with your do...while loop, the if and the else should have their content wrapped in curly braces to clearly show the compiler which parts of the code are relevant to the respective if/else.

```
package dowhileloops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhileLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String res, ans;
        
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("     ****     Do-While Loops     ****    ");
        System.out.println("=========================================\n");
        
        do{
            System.out.println("What is the color of the ocean?");
            System.out.println("\nA.) Orange\n\nB.) Green\n\nC.) Blue\n\nD.) Yellow\n\n");
            System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
            res = in.nextLine();

            if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                System.out.println("You are correct!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You are wrong!");
                System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Yes/No)");
                ans = in.nextLine();
            }
               
        }while(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));        
    }
    
}
```

Without a curly brace, the compiler will assume that only the very next line is needed for the else, and the end result looks something like the following:

```
if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
    System.out.println("You are correct!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("You are wrong!");
}
System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Yes/No)");
ans = in.nextLine();
```

The 'would you like to try again', and 'ans = in.nextLine()' are placed outside the else, hence the result you are getting.